# How can I sort and get sorted data by data-weight attribute? Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJCAO.png)[after using a code from @Justinas]

```
<div>
        <span class="r1 c1 d1" data-weight="3"></span>
        <span class="r1 c2" data-weight="2"></span>
        <span class="r1 c3 d2" data-weight="3"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="r2 c1" data-weight="2"></span>
        <span class="r2 c2 d1 d2" data-weight="4"></span>
        <span class="r2 c3" data-weight="2"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="r3 c1 d2" data-weight="3"></span>
        <span class="r3 c2" data-weight="2"></span>
        <span class="r3 c3 d1" data-weight="3"></span>
    </div>
```

So, those are spans and divs i got, I'm making a Tic Tac Toe game (computer vs player) and it should work like i cant beat computer. I put data-weight attributes to show how much worth is exact span. I have problems with attack function- I need to make it like it attacks player at first in most valuable spans (middle row and column, then diagonals, and then all other /more details in picture added [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxX50.png) )
I really don't know how to make a function to get all these data-weights and actually sort them in descending order to choose the most valuable span of all available... Thank You!

I made before a function that just attacked in every span in order of appearance not by data-weight.

```
    function attack() {
            var span = ['.r1 c1 d1', '.r2 c1', '.r3 c1 d2', '.r1 c2', '.r2 c2 d1 d2', '.r3 c2', '.r1 c3 d2', '.r2 c3', '.r3 c3 d1'];
            var weight = $('[data-weight]');
            var tempLoop = true;
            $.each(weight, function (k, span){
                var weight= $(weight).data('weight');
                $(span).each(function () {
                    if (tempLoop) {
                        if (isNaN($(this).data("full"))) {
                            $(this).data("full", 1)
                                    .data("value", -1)
                                    .html("<i class=\"fa fa-times\"></i>");
                            console.log("attack");
                            tempLoop = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
        }
```

Comment: Start with creating correct selectors `'.r1 c1 d1'` should be `'.r1.c1.d1'`

Comment: also share other information like usage of `.data("full")` and `.data("value")`

Comment: If you are trying to create a game app with complex calculation in the future, I suggest using light JS libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [underscrore](http://underscorejs.org/). Data manipulation made easy.

Comment: Are you trying to sort all `span`s in the example, based on their `data-weight` attribute? Also should they be sorted for each `div` or for all `div`s?

Comment: @trashr0x hi, i have to sort all spans from all three divs, so i can get the most valuable place to put computers move in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.sort()` function and compare `.data('weight')` of two elements, than you will have sorted elements by-weight, loop it or select first that has highest weight. Apply relative weight to *attack* that cell first

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.table span')
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return $(b).data('weight') - $(a).data('weight');
    })
    .each(function(k, i) {
      var $this = $(this);
      setTimeout(function () {
        $this.text(k + '/' + $this.data('weight'));
      }, k * 200);
    });
});
```

```css
.table {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.table div {
  height: 100px;
}
.table span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #555;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{attack-order / cell-weight}
<hr/>
<div class="table">
  <div>
    <span class="r1 c1 d1" data-weight="3"></span>
    <span class="r1 c2" data-weight="2"></span>
    <span class="r1 c3 d2" data-weight="3"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="r2 c1" data-weight="2"></span>
    <span class="r2 c2 d1 d2" data-weight="4"></span>
    <span class="r2 c3" data-weight="2"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="r3 c1 d2" data-weight="3"></span>
    <span class="r3 c2" data-weight="2"></span>
    <span class="r3 c3 d1" data-weight="3"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Example of game**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  computerMove();

  $('.table span:not(.full)').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('full player');
    computerMove();
    checkWinner();
  });
});

function computerMove() {
  $('.table span:not(.full)')
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return $(b).data('weight') - $(a).data('weight');
    })
    .first()
    .addClass('full computer');
}

function checkWinner() {
  if ($('.table span:not(.full)').length == 0) {
    // Do your logic of winning here:
    var hasWon = Math.random() > 0.5;

    if (hasWon) {
      alert('You have won');
    } else {
      alert('You have lost');
    }
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}

function restartGame() {
  $('.table span').removeClass('full');
  computerMove();
}
```

```css
.table {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.table div {
  height: 100px;
}
.table span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #555;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.table span.full {
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
}
.table span:not(.full):hover {
  background-color: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{attack-order / cell-weight}
<hr/>
<div class="table">
  <div>
    <span class="r1 c1 d1" data-weight="3"></span>
    <span class="r1 c2" data-weight="2"></span>
    <span class="r1 c3 d2" data-weight="3"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="r2 c1" data-weight="2"></span>
    <span class="r2 c2 d1 d2" data-weight="4"></span>
    <span class="r2 c3" data-weight="2"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="r3 c1 d2" data-weight="3"></span>
    <span class="r3 c2" data-weight="2"></span>
    <span class="r3 c3 d1" data-weight="3"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. I have a question, on players click it returns a some bunch of numbers and slashes, so I don't get how to get to write in exact most valuable span. I added a screenshot to my question higher, so you could understand

Comment: @GreidanePatricia In my code it's the line `$this.text(...)` that changes element text. Instead, you can use other code to process that field.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to sort an array by weight in ascending order:

```
var span = ['.r1.c1.d1', '.r2.c1', '.r3.c1.d2', '.r1.c2', '.r2.c2.d1.d2', '.r3.c2', '.r1.c3.d2', '.r2.c3', '.r3.c3.d1'];

var sorted = [];

for(var i in span){
    sorted.push( $(""+span[i]).attr("data-weight") );
}

sorted = sorted.sort();
```

`sorted` array contains all weights sorted by its value